# Count the number of previous occurrences using a time window, not a fixed window size

Tags: r, window, dplyr, aggregate

I have a dataset like the following, the last column is desired output.

```
   DX_CD  AID      date2  <count.occurences.1000.days>
1  272.4 1649 2007-02-10   0 or N/A
2 V58.67 1649 2007-02-10   0<-  (excluding the same day). OR 1
3 787.91 1649 2010-04-14   0
4 788.63 1649 2011-03-10   1
5 493.90 4193 2007-09-13   0 or N/A  #new AID
6 787.20 6954 2010-02-25   0 or N/A  #new AID
.....
```

I want to compute the column (count.occurences.1000.days)  that counts the number of previous occurrences within X days (e.g. X=1000) by AID.

The first value is 0 or N/A because there is no previous record before record #1 for AID=1649. The second value is 0 because this event occurs on the same day as record #1. Third value is 0 because there are records older than 2010-04-14, but they are beyond 1000days. Fourth value is 1 because the record #3 happened within 1000 days. Same logic goes for AID=4193 and AID=6954

Can someone provide an idea, preferably vectorized?

Comment: Which number of previous occurrences are we counting in the new column?  Can you tidy up your sample table above?

Comment: It's an interesting question. It would help if you cleared up the data and offered a copy-paste way to create the example.

Comment: You might want to adapt `foverlaps` solution here http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28578977/1

Comment: I revised the description.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly the question, this should do

First, a sample of the data

```
 df <- data.frame(date2=days <- 
                 seq(as.Date("2008-12-30"), as.Date("2015-01-03"), by="days"),
             AID=sample(c(1649, 4193, 6954, 3466), 2196, replace=T), 
             count=(rep.int(1,2196)))
```

Now we group by the 1000 days from max to min

```
df$date.bin <- Hmisc::cut2(df$date2, 
                 cuts=sort(seq(max(df$date2), length=10,by="-1000 days")))
```

Now we use cumsum on the grouped variables

```
res <-df %>% dplyr::arrange(date.bin, AID) %>% group_by(date.bin, AID) %>% 
      mutate(cumsum=cumsum(count))
```

Comment: What do you mean by random? Unsorted?

Comment: I understand your code now, sorta. 2 events can be within say 30 days, but assigned to different date bins. So it does not seem to be the correct answer.

Comment: Hi, I do not understand what you are trying to do this time.  Please check the overlap join for data.table.   In other words,  a record with date a can self-join with another record with date b only if the a>b & a-b<1000.  I believe my problem can be solved using overlap join for data.table package. However I am still wondering whether there is an easy way to do it using dplyr.